# Does $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ have a non-empty boundary?

Tags: differential-topology

> Does $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ have a non-empty boundary?

**Edit:**

I've shown that $1$ is a regular value, and hence $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ is a three-dimensional manifold as Ted's hint. But I am not sure about what to do next. One more step please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Prove it is a $3$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: er....... yes, I got that.... but i can't get conclusion about boundary...

Comment: If every point has a neighborhood diffeo to an open set in $\mathbb R^3$, what do you conclude?

Comment: Hi Ted, it is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{H}^3$ hence does not have boundary. I thought "manifold" means "manifold with or without boundary", but now I realized "manifold" means "manifold without boundary". thank you :)

Comment: Yup! Terminology is important :)

Comment: You might want to accept an answer if this question is settled to your satisfaction.

Comment: Oh, yes I should have accepted! Sorry Ted. :-) Once again: thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since $1$ is a regular value of the determinant function, $\det^{-1}\{1\} = \mathrm{SL}(2;\mathbb{R})$ is a submanifold of the two-by-two matrices. In particular, since it is a manifold, it has no boundary.

Comment: This is not quite right. Where did $-1$ come from?

Comment: My fevered imagination. I'm used to working with $\mathrm{PSL}(2;\mathbb{R})$, where you have to ignore $\pm I$, so I jumped to the conclusion that "determinant one" really means "determinant plus/minus one." Thanks for the catch!